# User only sees certain data from database on django site

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

On my site I only want certain user to see what they "own" from my database. For example, if Bob owns houses 1, 2 and 3, he should only be able to see stuff related to those houses.

Lets say my models looks something like this:

```
class Houses(models.Model):
    houseid = models.models.AutoField(db_column='houseID', primary_key=True).
    owner = models.CharField(db_column='owner', max_length=50) 
    size = models.FloatField(db_column='size')  
    rooms = models.FloatField(db_column='rooms)  
    floors = models.FloatField(db_column='floors') 
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='notes', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class HouseData(models.Model):
    houseid = models.ForeignKey(Houses, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='houseID')
    date = models.DateField()
    electricity = models.FloatField(db_column='electricity') 
    water = models.FloatField(db_column='water')
```

How would I restrict what the user sees on the site?

EDIT: Just for clarification, the user name and the owner name are the same

Comment: where is the `user` field? Is it the `owner` one?

Comment: The user and owner are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a ForeignKey to the User model rather than a CharField for the owner; then you can filter based on comparing that to `request.user`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use this?

`HouseData.objects.filter(houseid__owner=owner_name_here)`

Comment: I want it based on who logs into the site. So if person x logs in, i want to make sure that the only data that appears on the site corresponds to person x. With the code you provided, how would you make sure that the information displayed is that of the person who logged in?

Comment: Please, show code where you want this activity to happen. We cannot help you otherwise. Show your views, maybe.